# Get return value of build configuration

Tags: java, batch-file, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-cdt, buildconfiguration

I create a CDT eclipse plugin with specific build configuration. I use the `setBuildCommand()` and `setBuildArguments()` functions which call to a batch file.

My current code is:

```
ICProjectDescriptionManager mngr = CoreModel.getDefault().getProjectDescriptionManager();
ICProjectDescription des = mngr.createProjectDescription(project, false);
ManagedProject mProj = new ManagedProject(des);
Configuration cfg = new Configuration(mProj, null, "my.configuration.id", "MyConfiguration");
cfg.setBuildCommand("script.bat");
cfg.setBuildArguments(arg1 + " " + arg2);
```

I would like to get a return code from that batch file but I can't find a way to get it.

Any idea? Maybe you know how to add a marker to the project which will hold the information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

correct me if I'm wrong, but programatically creating a CProject definition is bad mojo. My answer will then be with using the 'standard' plugin.xml + Activator model (like when you make a new plugin project from template).

I think you're looking for an IErrorParser, which can parse the output from your BAT file.

**MyExErrorParser.java**

```
import org.eclipse.cdt.core.*
import org.eclipse.core.resources.*;

public class MyExErrorParser implements IErrorParser {

    public MyExErrorParser() {
    }

    @Override
    public boolean processLine(String line, ErrorParserManager eoParser) {

        IProject p = ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace().getRoot()
                                            .getProject("hello_world");

        p.getFile("main.c");

        if(line.contains("my_error_id_str")) {

            int err_lvl = IMarkerGenerator.SEVERITY_ERROR_RESOURCE;

            ProblemMarkerInfo marker = new ProblemMarkerInfo(p , 5, "bad", 
                                                             err_lvl,
                                                             "foo");

            eoParser.addProblemMarker(marker);

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

**Ideal**

when '**processLine()**' gets called, you have the opportunity to check the environment var **%ERRORLEVEL%** (or $? in linux)

- I can't for the life of me figure out how to get the *currentBuilder.*Environment() map which you would use to check that. But your var should be there
- I am guess the Environment() path is a monsterous rat-hole of time to try to figure out. XXX

**Proposed**

- just add the %ERRORLEVEL% check into your BAT file where you need it. If ERRORLEVEL >0, then output a message **"my_error_id_str**. It is then very easy for your IErrorParser above to evaluate it.

**Supplemental**

Here is a toolchain that exercises the above code. This example calls a shell script as its build command, with no arguments. I think this may be more of what you're ultimately after? Either way, it will be many times over easier to extend/maintain then the programmatic-implementation you used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension
         point="org.eclipse.cdt.managedbuilder.core.buildDefinitions">
      <projectType
            buildArtefactType="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe"
            id="Toolchain.projectType1"
            isAbstract="false"
            name="Justin">
         <configuration
               artifactExtension="o"
               buildArtefactType="org.eclipse.cdt.build.core.buildArtefactType.exe"
               cleanCommand="rm -rf"
               id="Toolchain.configuration1"
               name="Debug">
            <toolChain
                  errorParsers="exErrorParser"
                  id="Toolchain.toolChain1"
                  isAbstract="false"
                  name="Example Toolchain"
                  supportsManagedBuild="true"
                  targetTool="Toolchain.tool1">
               <builder
                     command="make"
                     errorParsers="exErrorParser"
                     id="Toolchain.builder1"
                     isAbstract="false"
                     isVariableCaseSensitive="false"
                     name="Builder">
               </builder>
               <tool
                     command="/home/jmreina/example.sh
                     commandLinePattern="${COMMAND}"
                     errorParsers="exErrorParser"
                     id="Toolchain.tool1"
                     isAbstract="false"
                     name="Example Tool">
                  <inputType id="Toolchain.inputType1" multipleOfType="false" primaryInput="true" sources="c"></inputType>
                  <outputType id="Toolchain.outputType1" outputs="txt" primaryOutput="true"></outputType>
               </tool>
            </toolChain>
         </configuration>
      </projectType>
   </extension>
   <extension
         id="id1"
         name="name"
         point="org.eclipse.cdt.core.ErrorParser">
      <errorparser
            class="MyExErrorParser"
            id="exErrorParser"
            name="MyExParserName">
      </errorparser>
   </extension>
</plugin>
```